# Writing columns into a text file

Tags: java, string, multiple-columns, filewriter, writer

Before tagging my question as a duplicate question, please let me explain first!

I know using `String.format` will let the text to be written into two columns, but that is not what I need. Because using `String.format` just gives specified number of spaces between any two desirable strings. What I am looking is that if in the text file, we press `tab` key in Windows based systems, it jumps directly to the next column, or in other words, if we copy the content of the text file and paste it into some software like `Excel`, `SPSS` etc, it automatically pastes each column from text file into a separate column in the corresponding software. Here is my current code which does not satisfy my need:

```
String formatStr = "%20s %20s";
String query="some string";
int value="some int";
fop.write(String.format(formatStr,query,value));
fop.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
fop.flush();
```

Comment: If you just comma-separate (or tab separate) the columns, then copy-paste into a spreadsheet should paste the columns correctly. It may depend on the spreadsheet itself, though.

Comment: That is kind of an overhead to the whole work. After all, what would be the use of `String.format`? just put a `"  " ` between the strings will do the same.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Java or the format of the data, per se. Spreadsheets input/export data using csv (comma-separated) or tab-delimited, for historical reasons. Format the data accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want tab separated values:

```
String.format("%s\t%s", query, value);
```

`\t` is the escape code for the "tab" character.